# Use String text as Code in Visual Basic for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, string

For various reasons, I need to concatenate a text of the form `[NAME].Value` by changing the value of `NAME` to an inputbox entry.

Something like this:

```
Sub example()

      data_in = InputBox("Give me something: ")
 
      mystring1 = "[" & data_in & "].Value"
 
      a = Evaluate(mystring1) 'I know this is wrong, but I don't know how to do so.

End Sub
```

I know it can be done in other ways, and the example in which I want to use this code is not exactly this one, and while it can be done in several ways here, in the original code it can only be done this way.

I want, based on the input in the imputbox, to concatenate the string in whatever way, and subsequently cast that string as code to store the value in another variable, to be used later in the code.

I am not able to get VBA to read the string text as code. I have seen that there is a way that consists of creating a macro from this first macro, execute it, and then delete the recently created macro. The problem with this solution is that doing that I can't save the variable when returning to the initial macro (I don't want to use global variables).

Surely there must be a way?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: The code above returns Error 2015

Comment: `a = range(data_in).value`? That should work if data_in is a cell reference

Comment: Yes, that's also a solution. As I comment below, I was getting unnecessarily complicated. Thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a string as if it was code, you can use the evaluate function (exists in most languages)

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) mentions this example:

```
[a1].Value = 25 
Evaluate("A1").Value = 25 
 
trigVariable = [SIN(45)] 
trigVariable = Evaluate("SIN(45)") 
 
Set firstCellInSheet = Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Sheets(4).[A1] 
Set firstCellInSheet = _ 
    Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Sheets(4).Evaluate("A1")
```

Comment: Yes, I just found that. I was on my way to answer my own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the easiest way to do it, sorry for posting the question so soon.

Thanks to @Andreas for the solution. I'll write it here in case than could be useful to someone.

```
Sub example()

      data_in = InputBox("Give me something: ")
 
      a = Range(data_in).Value
 
      Debug.Print a

End Sub
```

In the end the simplest thing is the last thing you try...

Comment: Generally using evaluate syntaxes is bad. I don't know about VBA but other programming languages that could cause big issues and be used as an inject stuff

Comment: You should avoid the evaluate-function, just use the syntax as @Andreas wrote in his comments

Comment: @FunThomas I've changed the answer. Thanks!